# Why does my column wrap to the next line in skeleton framework

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have two divs that supposed to be on one line. one div is 1/3 the width of the line and the second is 2/3rd width. what isnt the second bigger div floating up to be on the same line as the smaller one.

```css
.home {
  border: 4px solid gray;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url('https://unsplash.it/1024/768');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-position: center center;
}
.top {
  background: black;
}
.bottom {
  background: blue;
}
.left-nav {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.right-content {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--Primary Page Layout
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<section class="home">
  <!--Middle Row-->
  <div class="row">

    <!--Top Row-->
    <div class="twelve columns top u-full-width">
      <h4 class="heading"><span class="demphasize">Teacher Application Submission for </span>Dwayne Neckles</h4>
    </div>

    <!--Navigation-->
    <div class="left-nav one-third column">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="community.html">Community</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="leadership.html">Leadership</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="right-content two-thirds column">

    </div>
    <!--Footer Row-->
    <div class="twelve columns u-full-width">
      <h6 class="byline demphasize">Developed For</h6>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/204/52" width="204" height="52" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap rows in `<div class="row">...</div>`

```css
.home {
border: 4px solid gray;   
background-image: radial-gradient(
      circle,
      rgba(0,0,0,0),
      rgba(0,0,0,.3)
    ),url('https://unsplash.it/1024/768');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: none;
background-position: center center;

}

.top{
  background: black;
}
.bottom{
  background
}
.left-nav {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.right-content {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/skeleton.2.02.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--Primary Page Layout
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<section class="home">
  <!--Middle Row-->
  <div class="row">

    <!--Top Row-->
    <div class="twelve columns top u-full-width">
      <h4 class="heading"><span class="demphasize">Teacher Application Submission for </span>Dwayne Neckles</h4>
    </div>

   </div>

    <!--Navigation-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="left-nav one-third column">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
          <li><a href="community.html">Community</a></li>
          <li><a href="leadership.html">Leadership</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="right-content two-thirds column">

    </div>
    </div>
    <!--Footer Row-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns u-full-width">
      <h6 class="byline demphasize">Developed For</h6><img src="https://unsplash.it/204/52" width="204" height="52" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Michael thank you I see the fix, but I thought per the framework guide it said nesting wasnt allowed with skeleton, thats why i didnt put the row into another. whats your take on that? when is it okay and when is it not? Also, why was my question downvoted?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see the row you already had open, I didn't mean to nest it. But in that case, you should close that first row since it is `.u-full-width` and start a new one for the navigation/content section, then have a unique row for the footer since it's full width, too. I went ahead and updated my answer to close that row and open a new one for your footer. I didn't downvote your post, but I'm assuming it's because you linked to a 3rd party site and didn't include all of the relevant code in your post.

Comment: Thanks i updated my question just for good practice. I was going for the nav/content section to be full width as well, so i can add `u-full-width` to that that middle row as well right?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Yeah if codepen ever dies and SO doesn't, if someone found your post on here, they wouldn't have the code relevant to your question if the codepen link didn't work. You don't need to add `.u-full-width` to rows, rows are 100% width by default. You add `.u-full-width` to elements to make them 100% width if they aren't 100% by default.